# Viewing DOM of Webview For Automated Testing Using Appium

Tags: android, cordova, webview, appium

I'm attempting to use Appium to automate a Hybrid Android Application created using PhoneGap 2.3. Currently I am able to switch to the web view context, my only problem is I don't know the IDs of the DOM elements I'm wishing to manipulate.

Is there a way to view the DOM of the webview my app is displaying? Are there any commands which will post all the elements within the page? All I need is a basic understanding of what these elements are named.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured out that Chrome has an awesome inspector tool that allows you to see the DOM of any WebView! This works with either an emulator or a phone plugged in via USB.

Comment: any chance you can post an example?

Comment: @GilMoshayof sure thing, check this out and let me know if you need more information https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: can you share the chrome plugin name?

Comment: @HarshNigam see the link I shared above. I believe it comes native with chrome.

Comment: you can also use selendroid inspector tool for android API level < 19